# Execute a function as parameter in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

Let's say we have the class `Obj` and this main:

```
class Obj
{
   public:
     void func1(int n) {}
     void func2(std:string n) {}
};

std::vector<Obj> retrieveObjs()
{
    std::vector<Obj> result;
    // ...
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    // Call func1 for all obj
    {
      auto objs = retrieveObjs();  
      for (auto& obj : objs)       
      {
         obj.func1(100);
      }
    }

    // Call func2 for all obj
    {
      auto objs = retrieveObjs();  
      for (auto& obj : objs)       
      {
         obj.func2("xxx");
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to have a generic function to invoke specific function from all objs like the following pseudocode.

```
void invokeAll(FUNCTION f, PARAM p)   // pseudocode
{
   auto objs = retrieveObjs();
   for (auto& obj : objs)       
   {
     obj.f(p); 
   }
}

int main() // pseudocode
{
    invokeAll(func1, 100);
    invokeAll(func2, "xxx");
}
```

I don't know how to replace `FUNCTION` and `PARAM` to make this work.

Is that possible with template/lambda/for_each or similar tricks to do that?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Try it and come back with problems if you run into any. You have a wealth of related questions here at your disposal.

Comment: Well there's [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). Or [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn). As well as plain old pointers to member functions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Your comment is an answer in fact, consider formatting it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is a good use case for *pointer to member function*, which the syntax look like this:

```
// get the pointer to the function.
auto funPtr = &Obj::func1;

Obj obj;

// call the method using the function pointer
obj.(*funPtr)();
```

In your case, you can receive the function pointer as parameter and the arguments as a pack.

```
// F is the type of the function pointer.
// As arguments and return type of `f` can change, so it's type `F` can.
template<typename F, typename... Args>
void invokeAll(F f, Args... args) {
    for (auto&& obj : retrieveObjs()) {
      // We call member `f` with `obj`
      // We expand the pack `args` to send it as multiple arguments
      obj.(*f)(args...); 
    }
}
```

You will be able to call the function in a similar way you wanted:

```
// Notice the member function pointer syntax
invokeAll(&Obj::func1, 100);

// Work with multiple arguments, [100, "test"] will be packed into `args`
invokeAll(&Obj::func2, 100, "test");
```

---

In C++17, with `std::invoke`, you can generalize your case even further by allowing any type of function that takes a `Obj` as parameter:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
void invokeAll(F f, Args... args) {
    for (auto&& obj : retrieveObjs()) {
      // invoke function `f` with `obj` as it's object and `args` as parameter.
      std::invoke(f, obj, args...); 
    }
}
```

If you want, right now, supporting more kind of function, including lambdas, you can use `void_t` style sfinae:

```
// The compiler will pick this function if `obj.(*f)(args...)` can compile
template<typename F, typename... Args>
auto invokeAll(F f, Args... args) -> void_t<decltype(std::declval<Obj>().(*f)(args...))> {
    //                   Here's the constraint ------^
    for (auto&& obj : retrieveObjs()) {
      obj.(*f)(args...); 
    }
}

// The compiler will pick this function if `f(obj, args...)` can compile
template<typename F, typename... Args>
auto invokeAll(F f, Args... args) -> void_t<decltype(f(std::declval<Obj>(), args...))> {
    //                   Here's the constraint ------^
    for (auto&& obj : retrieveObjs()) {
      f(obj, args...); 
    }
}
```

`void_t` is defined as follow:

```
template<typename...>
using void_t = void;
```

Then, with that, you unlock this syntax too:

```
invokeAll([](Obj& obj, int a){
    // this block will be called for each `obj` in `retrieveObjs`
}, 100);
```

If you want to support non-copiable types too, look for *perfect forwarding*.

Comment: Really, I'd be tempted to just take a lambda and make the caller do the glue, rather than using a member function pointer, in C++11 and 14.

Comment: I must admit that I prefer not use member function pointers too. Lambda are a bliss. However, member function pointers are the closest thing to what OP desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class F, class R>
void invoke_on_range( F&& f, R&& r ) {
  std::for_each( r.begin(), r.end(), std::forward<F>(f) );
}
```

this takes a range and invokes the lambda on each element of the range.

```
int main() {
  invoke_on_range( [](Obj& obj){ obj.func1(100); }, retrieveObjs() );
  invoke_on_range( [](Obj& obj){ obj.func2("xxx"); }, retrieveObjs() );
}
```

There is a bit of boilerplate to write the lambda, but the structure becomes not your problem.

---

I find this useful sometimes as well:

```
template<class F, class...Args>
void invoke_on_each( F&& f, Args&&...args ) {
  using discard=int[];
  (void)discard{0,(void(
    f( std::forward<Args>(args) )
  ),0)...};
}
```

This takes a lambda `f` and a set of `args...`.  It runs `f` once on each `args...`.  The strange `discard` trick involves making an array of all `0`s and throwing it away (which the optimizer will not do) in order to generate a context where `...` will do exactly what we want.

Hiding the fact you are operating on `retrieveObjs` does not seem worth writing another wrapping function, but that can be done as well.

If you want to split the interface from implementation, you can replace the `class F` and `F&&` with `std::function<void(Obj&)>` for a modest performance cost.